# Need help on this Text message decoder (C++) exercise

Tags: c++

These are the directions:

1. Use `getline()` to get a line of user input into a string. Output the line. (3 pts)      
   **Ex:**
   **Enter text:** IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
   **You entered:** IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
2. Search the string (using `find()`) for common abbreviations and print a list of each found abbreviation along with its decoded meaning. (3 pts) 
   **Ex:**
   **Enter text:** IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
   **You entered:** IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.

Support to these abbreviations:

**BFF** -- best friend forever
**IDK** -- I don't know
**JK** -- just kidding
**TMI** -- too much information
**TTYL** -- talk to you later

I've been trying to code and get 6/6 possible points on this but I end up getting 3/6.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string input;

cout << "Enter text: ";
getline(cin, input);

cout << endl <<"You entered: " << input << endl;

if (input.find("BFF") && input.find("IDK"))
{
cout << "BFF: best friend forever" << endl;
cout << "IDK: I don't know" << endl;
} 

if (input.find("JK") && input.find("TMI") && input.find("TTYL"))
{
   cout << "JK: just kidding" << endl;
   cout << "TMI: too much information" << endl;
   cout << "TTYL: talk to you later" << endl;
}
   return 0;
}
```

I'm not getting the last 3 points:

Compare output
0/2

Input
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.

Your output

Enter text:

You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.

BFF: best friend forever

IDK: I don't know

JK: just kidding

TMI: too much information

TTYL: talk to you later

Expected output 
Enter text:

You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.

BFF: best friend forever

IDK: I don't know

Compare output
0/1

Input
Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL

Your output

Enter text:

You entered: Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL

BFF: best friend forever

IDK: I don't know

Expected output

Enter text:

You entered: Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL

JK: just kidding

TMI: too much information

TTYL: talk to you later

Comment: What if the input contains *only* `"BFF"`? Or only `"JK"`?

Comment: Also, please read e.g. [this `std::string::find` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and check what the function returns. Hint: It's not a boolean.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, but regardless if it's not boolean it will still work in his case unless somehow it returns a 0, which I highly doubt that function call will.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI `npos` is usually not zero, so even if the substring is not found the condition will think it is.

Comment: So do I have to change the conditional statement and make  the find () != npos or -1 in order to Check if the string was actually found or not?

Comment: nvm I got it. I had to use the proper syntax for the conditon.

whatever.find(~~~~) != string::npos. I though that i didn't need the "string ::"  part because I did #include <String> but i was wrong. derp.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your function calls evaluate to true at some points and false at others. Find() returns the position of the first char of the found substring, or npos = -1 if no such substring is found. A true statement is one that evaluates to a nonzero number. False evaluates to 0.

In your compare output 0/2, everything evaluates to nonzero values. Hence, everything is printed. In 0/1, one value must've been 0. BFF and IDK print since they're -1,  and the rest doesn't.
(Just my 2¢, maybe someone can confirm what the values in your code evaluate to)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string text;
cout << "Input an abbreviation:" << endl;
getline(cin, text);

if (text.find("LOL") != string::npos){
   cout << "laughing out loud" << endl;
}

else if (text.find("IDK") != string::npos){
   cout << "I don't know" << endl;
}

else if (text.find("BFF") != string::npos){
   cout << "best friends forever" << endl;
}

else if (text.find("IMHO") != string::npos){
   cout << "in my humble opinion" << endl;
}

else if (text.find("TMI") != string::npos){
   cout << "too much information" << endl;
}

else{
   cout << "Unknown" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //for already defined String Value of BFF, IDK, JK, TMI and TTYL.

   if (userIn.find("BFF") != string::npos){
      cout << "BFF: " << BFF << endl;
   }
   if (userIn.find("IDK") != string::npos){
      cout << "IDK: " << IDK << endl;
   }
   if (userIn.find("JK") != string::npos){
      cout << "JK: " << JK << endl;
   }
   if (userIn.find("TMI") != string::npos){
      cout << "TMI: " << TMI << endl;
   }
   if (userIn.find("TTYL") != string::npos){
      cout << "TTYL: " << TTYL << endl;
   }
```

The `.find()` does not return a boolean value so it's not true or false. `find(item)` returns the index of the first item occurrence, else returns string::npos (a constant defined in the string library).
So, you compare it to `string::npos` to see if the string you want is there or not.

Hope it explained.

Answer (score -3):

delete the condition:
input.find("IDK")